# How to add Mark Down styles to the Azure DevOps website

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm trying to add the ability to see Mark Down styles in the Azure DevOps website or somehow inject the CSS,

For example: when navigating to Repos I have README.md which I want to look like the Microsoft standard MD documentations, [!TIP], [!WARNING], and other styles don't seem to be supported out of the box.

Any suggestions? maybe even creating a plugin for Azure DevOps website (how do I do that?)

Here's an example of how I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hi @Cid - if you scroll down at the URL you just sent, you can see Microsoft is having a "Note" which they also use in the Mark Down, but it looks like this tag like "Tip" and "Warning" is using some custom style.

Comment: Also, I'm using Docs Authoring Pack in VS Code, which seems to offer valid Mark Down tags.

Answer (score 4):

You may try the following styles:

```
**WARNING**: 
Be careful!
```

[image]

```
### Warning: 
Be careful!
```

[image]

```
> **WARNING**: Be careful
```

[image]

```
> :warning: **Be careful!**
```

[image]

```
| WARNING: Be careful! |
| --- |
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, this is helpful but does not fully answer my question, I like the :warning: and I wonder if there are more icons available, but my goal is to have my ReadMe.MD files in each Azure DevOps Repo look exactly like Microsoft articles.

Comment: You can check the supported emoji here: https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/.